# Is there a way to check if firebase collection is empty without an asynchronous call?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase colud database. I'm trying to understand how to check if collection is empty (does not have documnets). From other topics I learn that I can use:

```
        groupRef.collection("cars")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        //code
                    }
                });
```

But is there a non asynchronous call that I can do just for checking if the collection is empty or do I have to use the code above?

Answer (score 1):

All Firebase queries are asynchronous, there is no way to see if a collection does not have documents synchronously, even seeing the collection from the console will incur on an asynchronous call.

Answer (score 0):

Its not recommended to do this. If you don't use an asynchronous call, it could freeze you UI thread and your app will crash. So making this asynchronous call ensures your UI is functioning while the data from Firebase can be fetched. Don't do this even if you can somehow.